# Android: how can i find file path

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

i'm using a source code like this:

```
PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("plot.txt"));
fout.println("#\tX\tY");
```

i want to find path of "plot.txt", any help?
best regards.

Comment: Keep it in your own hands: don't supply a relative path so you don't know where the file 'lands'. Decide where you want to output the file (internal, external or removable memory) first and supply full path to the writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use File instead of FileWriter you can easily call the getPath() or getAbsolutePath() method from File.

I have looked in the api of PrintWriter and FileWriter and there are no methods to determine the path.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PrintWriter.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html

Example:

```
File f = new File("test/.././file.txt");
System.out.println(f.getPath());
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: how can i use file and write in file?

Comment: It could be the same default path by File and FileWriter. But it is not documented in your reference link as far as i can see.

Comment: `If you use File instead of FileWriter`. Please rephrase: File is no replacement for FileWriter.

Comment: @greenapps in this case it is, PrintWriter can take a File Object too.

Comment: `how can i use file and write in file? `. You cannot. You are misinformed.

Comment: Yes PrintWriter can take a File as parameter. I have seen that. But if it takes a filename it is not documented what will happen where. And it cannot write to the file and OP needs that. It is no replacement.

Comment: @ManuZi have can i write in text file by "File"?

Comment: i used "PrintWriter" and "File" as parameter, f.getAbsolutePath() shows "/Plot.txt". but i need full path like this: "sdcard/my app/plot.txt"

Comment: yes you can write text in an file. To the other point, thats the point that would greenapps pointed to. you decided where the file would be placed eg (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5605823/1809221)