# Getting absolute path on android

Tags: android, c++, fopen

I've got c++ code in which I try to get a file from a directory on an android device. I've tried different ways to set the path which I pass to the fopen() function like:
 /Android/data/com.myapp/files/Blip.wav
There actually is this file. But I guess that this is not a proper way to write a path. (The example was obtained by the java code )

```
getContext().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/Blip.wav"
```

Comment: Any reason you can't call that java code in your jni, or have that path passed into your c++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the complete path of file from android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605313/how-to-get-the-complete-path-of-file-from-android-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There actually is this file

Since I have never seen an Android device with an `/Android` directory, that is unlikely.

What *would* fit is if you are looking at `/Android/data/com.myapp/files/Blip.wav` in a desktop file manager, using a USB or similar connection. In that case, `Android/data/com.myapp/files/Blip.wav` is a relative path in external storage. Specifically, it maps to:

```
new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(), "Blip.wav")
```

Comment: sorry but this is internal storage

there also was a variant with data/data/com.myapp/files/Blip.wav
but none of them worked

Comment: @AOY: "this is internal storage" -- no, it is not [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for that. How couldn't I understand that before?))

Answer (score 1):

Try using this.

```
    File root=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file=new File(root,"/PersonData/Blip.wav");
```

Here personData is the name of folder