# Alternative for file dump

Tags: android, c++

I'm trying to use `fopen()` in a .cpp file as

```
fp = fopen("/sdcard/inputdump.txt", "wb");
```

to dump some data into it and later analyse the contents of the file.

The problem is fp is always `NULL` irrespective of the path mentioned in the `fopen()`. So is there any other way we can use instead of dumping it into a file?

Comment: Why you added `android` tag?

Comment: If you are on android: Do you have the permission to write to "/sdcard/" with your app?

Comment: The obvious thing to check would be `errno` - _why_ is `fp==NULL` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `freopen("./path/to/file.txt", "w", stdout);` you can redirect standard output to file and save your staff just using `cout`. As an example

```
cout << "write this text to file" << endl;
```

Also `ofstream` do the same without changing the standard output.

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
...
ofstream out("./path/to/file.txt", ofstream::out);
out << "write this text to file" << endl;
```

PS: See [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) `fopen` has not `b` option.

Comment: where does `"./path/to/file.txt"` point to in the physical file st\ystem?

Comment: @pskink Look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283619/getting-absolute-path-on-android). There is no note about what platform(android) you are asking the question text!

Comment: there was a tag `android` that was deleted one minute ago

Comment: @pskink If you ask this Q for a PC app. `.` means the current location of executable file in the `"./path/to/file.txt"`. So simply `./file.txt` means that your file is beside the app executable.

Comment: i know that but on android platform there is no notion of "current location"

Comment: @pskink You must mention it in the question statement or even title. Someone removed the tag since he/she think it is redundant.

Comment: @pskink I am not an android expert but I think it gives you a folder for your  data which is temporary. you must get its path using some [API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595324/creating-temporary-files-in-android-with-ndk).

Comment: i think OP problem is file permissions: (note he is using the absolute file path) but still his code does not work

Comment: @pskink You need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731314/android-ndk-write-file)